# SQL Server 2008 Witness Server error

Tags: sql-server, database

Our SQL Server 2008 mirroring was setup and working a few weeks ago with a 3rd server as the witness.  However, we started getting the following error message recently:

> Database mirroring connection error 4
>   'An error occurred while receiving
>   data: '64(The specified network name
>   is no longer available.)'.' for
>   'TCP://COMPUTER-NAME:5022'.

The machines can ping each other so it's not a connectivity or a firewall issue.

Any idea how to resolve this error?

RESOLVED: Our hosting provider changed our firewall setting to block port 5022.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a communications problem, but I found this [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabasemirroring/thread/f3088009-4e2e-4695-b2ad-5c4a2cc55f69) for some good troubleshooting tips.  I know it's sql server 2005 and not 2008, but it might help point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Attach profiler to all 3 instances (principal, mirror, witness) and monitor the [Audit Database Mirroring Login Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190746.aspx) and the [Broker:Connection Event Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190760.aspx). The text data will contain details about the reason for disconnect.